# Autodetect possible arguments in shell script for completion

Tags: bash, shell, unix, zsh

Here's a shell script that does some stuff according to with what parameter it was called:

```
if [ $1 = "-add" ] 
then
    ...
elif [ $1 = "-remove" ]
    ...
else
    ...
fi
```

A script is an executable one (a link to it was created in the `/usr/bin` directory). So, I can call it from shell by specifying the link name added in `/usr/bin`.

What I want, is auto-detecting the possible arguments of script (in my case they are `-add`, `-remove`) during it calling. It means that when I'll type a command, related to script calling, then type `-re` and press a tab button it will suggest that it's `-remove` and autofill it for me.

How the arguments need to be defined to reach that?

Tried to create aliases in shell config file or few links in `/usr/bin` directory for all possible inputs and it was working fine, but I don't think it's a best solution for that.

Comment: Google for "bash completion".

Comment: Auto-detecting arguments of binaries or scripts is generally not possible. You may let the shell expect it instead with bash completion.

Comment: There may be a way to let bash completion system communicate with the script through an invisible argument but I wouldn't want digging into such complexity. Just a tip.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto-complete command line arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690655/auto-complete-command-line-arguments)

Comment: thanks for a quick reply, now I know where to dig

Answer (score 6):

While it does require some configuration outside of your script, adding autocomplete options is fairly easy.

Here's a simple example of a ~/.bash_completion file that adds auto completion of *--add* and *--remove* to command *yourscript*. In a real world case you'd probably want to generate the options by querying the script directly; they're hard coded here for simplicity.

```
_yourscript_complete()
{
    # list of options for your script
    local options="--add --remove"

    # current word being completed (provided by stock bash completion)
    local current_word="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"

    # create list of possible matches and store to ${COMREPLY[@}}
    COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "${options}" -- "$current_word"))
}
complete -F _yourscript_complete yourscript
```

Note that the ~/.bash_completion is only sourced  during login, so you'll need to spawn another login shell to see your changes in action. You may need to enable sourcing of user bash_completion files on your system, too.

The result:

```
$ yourscript --<tab><tab>
--add     --remove
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that bash/zsh completion is a powerful tool that can manage you shell input in the way you want.

In one of the other answers some explanations about how it works in bash were presented.

I'm a user of zsh, so, I think, it wouldn't be superfluous to show how I managed my task there:

1. Configuring `.zshrc` file:

   - adding folder for your autocomplete functions:

     `fpath=(~/.zsh-completions $fpath)`
   - enabling zsh tab-completion system:

     `autoload -U compinit & compinit`

   Note: above accented lines must be added to `~/.zshrc` file.
2. Adding a function for your script:

   After configuring .zshrc file, restarting zsh and typing `scriptname` in it, compinit() function will list all files with **underscope** from `$fpath` and find the one with first line that matches `#compdef scriptname`.

   So, a new file `_scriptname` that will hold a function for our script must be added to `~/.zsh-completions` directory. To let compinit() find this file on `scriptname` typing, as mentioned above, its first line must be: `#compdef scriptname`.
3. Let the arguments dancing:

   For zsh there are a lot of completion functions examples in `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion` directory. By finding the appropriate one there you can configure your shell input according to your tastes. For auto-detecting the attributes        (in my case they are `-add` and `-remove`) an `_attributes()` function in the `_scriptname` 
   file could be set in the next way:

   > ```
   > _arguments -s \            
   > '(-a --add)'{-a,--add}'[adding a new item to the basket]' \
   > '(-r --remove)'{-r,--remove}'[removing an item from the basket]'
   > ```

Eventually, after restarting zsh again, auto-detecting for `scriptname` is working as below:

> ```
> scriptname -<TAB>   => scriptname -      
>                        --add     -a  -- adding a new item to the basket                  
>                        --remove  -r  -- removing an item from the basket
>
> scriptname --a<TAB> => scriptname --add 
> scriptname --r<TAB> => scriptname --remove
> ```