# How to get tab completion for $PATH as an argument in a bash script?

Tags: bash, gnu, tab-completion

I have a very simple script that benchmark apps using the Vulkan API. it takes an argument from `$1`:

**benchmark-app:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

VK_INSTANCE_LAYERS=VK_LAYER_MESA_overlay VK_LAYER_MESA_OVERLAY_CONFIG=position=top-right $1
```

To use it, I run `benchmark-app example-game`. It will take the argument and execute as expected, but when using tab completion it looks in `./` not `$PATH`.

Comment: He... ?  Your script runs under your user I presume?  So it should have the same env. variables as you do when you login.  If your user can run `$1`, it should be ok from your script.  **1** does it work with the full path to the command you put in `$1`?  **2** Debug: add `which "$1"` as the first line of your script.  It should give your the proper path.  If no fix that.  **3** You could add `echo "$PATH"`, to see what PATH variable your script uses.    Please explain better "when using tab completion", what are you trying *exactly*.

Comment: @Nic3500 What I want is to be able to type `benchmark-app exa`, then press Tab on the keyboard and have it complete to `benchmark-app example-game`. `benchmark-app /usr/bin/exa`, then pressing Tab works. `benchmark-app example-game` also works, but the argument has to be typed word for word.

Comment: That might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690655/auto-complete-command-line-arguments or this https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/tabexpansion.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got tab completion working using GNU's `complete` command. I created the file `/etc/bash_completion.d/benchmark-app` and added this line: `complete -F _command benchmark-app`.